# Let $A=\{1,2,...,n(n-1)\}$ with $n\geq2$ a natural number. Determine all pairs $(x,y)$ with elements from $A$ having the property $x^2\ge y$.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A=\{1,2,...,n(n-1)\}$ with $n\geq2$ a natural number. Determine all pairs $(x,y)$ with elements from $A$ having the property $x^2\ge y$.
How to approach this type of counting problems?

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ supposed to be $x$ and $y$ or is something missing in the question?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's clear now!

Comment: Also I guess there should be a comma between $n-1$ and $n$. Otherwise one might think this is a product.

Comment: It's a product!

Comment: But then $1$ does not match the rule, is this supposed to be an exception?

Comment: No...For example, if n=2 the set is A={1,2}. If n=3, the set is A={1,2,3,4,5,6} and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $p=1$, then $q\leq p^2\implies q\leq 1\implies (1,1)$ is 1 such pair.

Then, set $p=2$, which gives $q\leq 4\implies (2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4)$ are 4 possible pairs

then for $p=3,$ no. of pairs comes out to be $9$

and so on..

**EDIT:**

it continues till $p=n-1,$ no. of pairs = $(n-1)^2$

and then for $p=n,...,n(n-1)$ every element in $A$ will do which gives $n(n-1)\cdot (n-1)^2$

Thus, total such pairs $=1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2+n(n-1)^3=\dfrac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}+n(n-1)^3$

Comment: I thought there can be a general formula which gives the number of pairs.

Comment: @user95553: I edited my solution.